# how to set primary and foreign key while creating a relation

Tags: yii

Hello I have two tables and trying to create a relationship between them.

OH_USERS (table)

user_id  (key)

agents

agent_id
user_id (key)

I need to get agents email from OH_USERS table   but  insted of using user_id as a key it uses agent_id as the key to relate two table. Due to which I dont get the right result.  Is there any where we can specifically define which field to use as a key  or its choosen whatever its kept in the database.

Answer (score 4):

The framework already has a solution for this. In the latests releases you can specify by hand what is the key you're going to use for the relation. [As explained in the doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail):

> In case you need to specify custom PK->FK association you can define it as array('fk'=>'pk')

In your case it'll look like the following:

```
'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'OH_USERS ', array('user_id'=>'user_id')),
```

If you don't stablish the relation this way, the framework looks for the primary key of foreign table, and use it to do the join.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me out. But don't you mean `array('user_id'=>'user_id')`?

Comment: @sucotronic, you'r a champ! Thanks this fixed my issue where I also had to use a non-primary key value as the foreign key for the related table.

Answer (score 0):

Go to agent model and define in relation this...

```
    'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'OH_USERS ', 'user_id'), 

//oh_users is your model class name of user and user_id is your foriegn key in agent table..
```

and now you use active record in your controller like this..

```
$agent = Agent::model()->with('user')->find('user_id=:user_id',array('user_id'=>$userid));
```

and now you fetch the email of user like this...

```
$agent['user']['email];
```

it will work good..

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question again:

you are fetching records from 'OH_USERS' so you need to define the relation with agent there:

```
'agent'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AgentModel', '' , 'on' => 't.user_id = agent.user_id'),
```

This way you are telling user model to make a relation with agent model on the basis of user_id and not the default agent_id

Comment: @sucotronic if that worked for you, would u please accept the answer  ?

Comment: @sucotronic no problem. Still accept your best answer whoever given, so other visitors can get the benefit also.